# TensorFlow: what activation function for numbers/floats?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to train TensorFlow for some data which are in range 0..100 for input and output. Normalised they are in range  0.0 .. 1.0. Input data are arrays of data and output data are (maller) arrays of data where all members of this array are filled.

So as an example, my data may look like this (just one row to explain it a bit more detailed):

```
Input: 5 10 34 28 10 100 56 68 99 1 67 13 22
Output: 1 19 89
```

And normalised:

```
Input: 0.05 0.10 0.34 0.28 0.10 1.00 0.56 0.68 0.99 0.01 0.67 0.13 0.22
Output: 0.01 0.19 0.89
```

For my layers, what activation functions should I use to reflect this range of my data types?

Comment: Are you asking about the _activation_ function - ie. the nonlinearity applied between layers of your network (like ReLU or sigmoid) or _loss_ function - the one used to judge the "goodness" of output 19 when 21 was expected (like mean squared error or cross-entropy)?

Comment: @Jatentaki the question is about the activation function